# Create a copy of a voided envelope in Docusign with Node js

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I'm working with the docusign's api/sdk and have a problem. I was searching to reactivate the envelope but it seems that the only way is create a copy of the voided envelope as a new envelope

How can I create a copy of a envelope that was decline by the signers and resend it? (Node js)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an envelope by setting the [`envelopeId` attribute](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/create/#schema__envelopedefinition_envelopeid) in the Envelopes:create API call.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot copy a voided envelope, only envelopes in **sent** or **completed** status can be copied.

More information about copying envelopes can be find in [this blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-cloning-envelope) including code snippets.